# Why is Hash Table insertion time complexity worst case is not N log N

Tags: time-complexity, hashtable

Looking at the fundamental structure of hash table. We know that it resizes WRT load factor or some other deterministic parameter. I get that if the resizing limit is reached within an insertion we need to create a bigger hash table and insert everything there. Here is the thing which I don't get.

Let's consider a hash table where each bucket contains an AVL - balanced BST. If my hash function returns the same index for every key then I would store everything in the same AVL tree. I know that this hash function would be a really bad function and would not be used but I'm doing a worst case scenario here. So after some time let's say that resizing factor has been reached. So in order to resize I created a new hash table and tried to insert every old elements in my previous table. Since the hash function mapped everything back into one AVL tree, I would need to insert all the N elements into the same AVL. N insertion on an AVL tree is N logN. So why is the worst case of insertion for hash tables considered O(N)?

Here is the proof of adding N elements into Avl three is N logN:
[Running time of adding N elements into an empty AVL tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809377/running-time-of-adding-n-elements-into-an-empty-avl-tree)

Comment: Usually buckets do not contain an AVL tree, but just a linked list (that is for example prepended). The idea is that collissions are quite rare, that it does not pay off to use a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: it depends on how the bucket is implemented. With a linked list, it can be done in *O(n)* under certain conditions. For an implementation with AVL trees as buckets, this can indeed, wost case, result in *O(n* log *n)*. In order to calculate the time complexity, the implementation of the buckets should be known.

Frequently a bucket is *not* implemented with an AVL tree, or a tree in general, but with a linked list. If there is a reference to the `last` entry of the list, appending can be done in *O(1)*. Otherwise we can still reach *O(1)* by *prepending* the linked list (in that case the buckets store data in reversed insertion order).

The idea of using a linked list, is that a dictionary that uses a reasonable hashing function should result in few collisions. Frequently a bucket has zero, or one elements, and sometimes two or three, but not much more. In that case, a simple datastructure can be faster, since a simpler data structure usually requires less cycles per iteration.

Some hash tables use *open addressing* where buckets are not separated data structures, but in case the bucket is already taken, the next free bucket is used. In that case, a search will thus iterate over the used buckets until it has found a matching entry, or it has reached an empty bucket.

The [Wikipedia article on *Hash table*s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) discusses how the buckets can be implemented.